# Asynchronous bulk data transfer

Tags: android, asynchronous, usb, transfer, bulk

I am working on USB communication between an Android Galaxy S III smartphone and a device which does not conform to Android Open Accessory device definition. I want to transfer asynchronously bulk data from the device to the host. The connection between the host and device works correctly, what has been verified by sending control commands to the device.

1. Can this transfer be done with an endpoint of the bulk type (USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) or it has to be the interrupt type (USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT) as it is specified in the MissileLauncher app sample?
2. Does the request.queue call fill the data buffer after the connection.requestWait returns or some other conditions need to be checked?

Answer (score 0):

You must do your bulk transfer with your bulk endpoints either you do asynchronous or synchronous transfer(USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK).

I can not give clear answer for you second question because I have too problem about this subject. I can fill my buffer with below code. Generally connection.requestWait() method is calling after  request.queu(...) method. But I have problem in this state

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
    request.initialize(usbDeviceModel.getConnection(), usbEndpoint2);
    request.queue(buffer, 512);

    if(request == usbDeviceModel.getConnection().requestWait()){
            Message msg = imageViewFragment.usbDataHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg.obj = buffer.array();
            imageViewFragment.usbDataHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
```

I want to send data to my activity with handler after if condition but I can not send when my device plugged in to android device. Only when I plugged out my device if condition is working and I can send data to activity with handler. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350251/android-asynchronous-bulk-transfer-with-usb-host-api#)